# Replace an element in a list only once - Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I want to replace an element in a list with a new value only at first time occurrence.
I wrote the code below but using it, all the matched elements will change.

```
replaceX :: [Int] -> Int -> Int -> [Int]
replaceX items old new = map check items where
check item  | item == old = new 
            | otherwise = item
```

How can I modify the code so that the changing only happen at first matched item?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The point is that `map` and `f` (`check` in your example) only communicate regarding how to transform individual elements. They don't communicate about how far down the list to transform elements: `map` always carries on all the way to the end.

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map _ []     = []
map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs
```

Let's write a new version of `map` --- I'll call it `mapOnce` because I can't think of a better name.

```
mapOnce :: (a -> Maybe a) -> [a] -> [a]
```

There are two things to note about this type signature:

1. Because we may stop applying `f` part-way down the list, the input list and the output list must have the same type. (With `map`, because the entire list will always be mapped, the type can change.)
2. The type of `f` hasn't changed to `a -> a`, but to `a -> Maybe a`.

   - `Nothing` will mean "leave this element unchanged, continue down the list"
   - `Just y` will mean "change this element, and leave the remaining elements unaltered"

So:

```
mapOnce _ []     = []
mapOnce f (x:xs) = case f x of
        Nothing -> x : mapOnce f xs
        Just y  -> y : xs
```

Your example is now:

```
replaceX :: [Int] -> Int -> Int -> [Int]
replaceX items old new = mapOnce check items where
    check item  | item == old = Just new 
                | otherwise   = Nothing
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the precise explanation! I learned a lot.

Answer (score 4):

You can easily write this as a recursive iteration like so:

```
rep :: Eq a => [a] -> a -> a -> [a]
rep items old new = rep' items
    where rep' (x:xs) | x == old  = new : xs
                      | otherwise = x : rep' xs
          rep' [] = []
```

Comment: I'm quite new to Haskell. may I ask what is the meaning of "Eq a=>" ?

Comment: That's a type constraint; it means is that `a` must be an instance of the Eq typeclass. It's needed so that `==` can be used.

Answer (score 4):

A direct implementation would be

```
rep :: Eq a => a -> a -> [a] -> [a]
rep _ _ [] = []
rep a b (x:xs) = if x == a then b:xs else x:rep a b xs
```

I like list as last argument to do something like

```
myRep = rep 3 5 . rep 7 8 . rep 9 1
```

Answer (score 3):

To be blunt, I don't like most of the answers so far.  dave4420 presents some nice insights on `map` that I second, but I also don't like his solution.

Why don't I like those answers?  Because you should be learning to solve problems like these by breaking them down into smaller problems that can be solved by simpler functions, preferably library functions.  In this case, the library is [`Data.List`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html), and the function is [`break`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html#v%3abreak):

> `break`, applied to a predicate `p` and a list `xs`, returns a tuple where first element is longest prefix (possibly empty) of `xs` of elements that do not satisfy `p` and second element is the remainder of the list.

Armed with that, we can attack the problem like this:

1. Split the list into two pieces: all the elements before the first occurence of `old`, and the rest.
2. The "rest" list will either be empty, or its first element will be the first occurrence of `old`.  Both of these cases are easy to handle.

So we have this solution:

```
import Data.List (break)

replaceX :: Eq a => a -> a -> [a] -> [a] 
replaceX old new xs = beforeOld ++ replaceFirst oldAndRest 
    where (beforeOld, oldAndRest) = break (==old) xs
          replaceFirst [] = []
          replaceFirst (_:rest) = new:rest
```

Example:

```
*Main> replaceX 5 7 ([1..7] ++ [1..7])
[1,2,3,4,7,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

So my advice to you:

1. Learn how to import libraries.
2. Study library documentation and learn standard functions.  [`Data.List`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html) is a great place to start.
3. Try to use those library functions as much as you can.
4. As a self study exercise, you can pick some of the standard functions from `Data.List` and write your own versions of them.
5. When you run into a problem that can't be solved with a combination of library functions, try to invent your own generic function that would be useful.

**EDIT:** I just realized that `break` is actually a [`Prelude`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html) function, and doesn't need to be imported.  Still, `Data.List` is one of the best libraries to study.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative using the [Lens library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens).

```
>import Control.Lens
>import Control.Applicative

>_find :: (a -> Bool) -> Simple Traversal [a] a                                   
>_find _ _ [] = pure []                                                           
>_find pred f (a:as) = if pred a                                                  
>                       then (: as) <$> f a                                       
>                       else (a:) <$> (_find pred f as)
```

This function takes a (a -> Bool) which is a function that should return True on an type 'a' that you wan to modify.

If the first number greater then 5 needs to be doubled then we could write:

```
>over (_find (>5)) (*2) [4, 5, 3, 2, 20, 0, 8]
[4,5,3,2,40,0,8]
```

The great thing about lens is that you can combine them together by composing them (.). So if we want to zero the first number <100 in the 2th sub list we could:

```
>over ((element 1).(_find (<100))) (const 0) [[1,2,99],[101,456,50,80,4],[1,2,3,4]]
[[1,2,99],[101,456,0,80,4],[1,2,3,4]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not the fastest solution, but easy to understand:

```
rep xs x y = 
  let (left, (_ : right)) = break (== x) xs 
  in left ++ [y] ++ right
```

**[Edit]**

As Dave commented, this will fail if x is not in the list. A safe version would be:

```
rep xs x y = 
  let (left, right) = break (== x) xs 
  in left ++ [y] ++ drop 1 right
```

**[Edit]**

Arrgh!!!

```
rep xs x y = left ++ r right where
  (left, right) = break (== x) xs 
  r (_:rs) = y:rs
  r [] = []
```

Comment: Although the pattern match will fail should `x` not occur in `xs`.

Comment: Re your edit: should `x` not occur in `xs`, your safe version will return `xs ++ [y]`. This is not what the other solutions do. I am not saying this is wrong (although I don't think it is what the OP wants, doubtless there are some situations where this behaviour is correct) but I do think it is worth noting.

Comment: Here's a hack: `rep xs x y = let (left, right) = break (== x) xs; (yes, no) = splitAt 1 right in left ++ [y | _ <- yes] ++ no`.

Answer (score 1):

```
replaceValue :: Int -> Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
replaceValue a b (x:xs) 
        |(a == x) = [b] ++ xs
        |otherwise = [x] ++ replaceValue a b xs
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an imperative way to do it, using `State` Monad:

```
import Control.Monad.State                                                  

replaceOnce :: Eq a => a -> a -> [a] -> [a]
replaceOnce old new items = flip evalState False $ do
  forM items $ \item -> do
    replacedBefore <- get
    if item == old && not replacedBefore
      then do
        put True
        return new
      else
        return old
```