# Removing the first instance of x from a list

Tags: list, haskell

I am new to Haskell and have been trying to pick up the basics.

Assume I have the following list y:

`3:3:2:1:9:7:3:[]`

I am trying to find a way to delete the first occurrence of 3 in list y. Is this possible using simple list comprehension?

What I tried (this method deletes all instances from a list):

```
deleteFirst _ [] = [] 
deleteFirst a (b:bc) | a == b    = deleteFirst a bc 
                     | otherwise = b : deleteFirst a bc
```

Comment: `3:3:2:1:9:7:3` is not a list. You probably mean `[3,3,2,1,9,7,3]` which is syntactic shugar for `3:3:2:1:9:7:3:[]`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Sorry, that was a typo, see edited.

Comment: You're trying to re-implement `Data.List.delete`, which is defined as `deleteBy (==)`. If you're stuck, you can always have a [look at the source code on Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/Data-List.html#deleteBy).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as other already mentioned list comprehension is not an appropriate solution to this task (difficult to terminate the execution at one step).

You've almost written the correct solution, just in the case of equality with the matched value you had to terminate the computation by returning the rest of list without the matched element:

```
deleteFirst _ [] = [] 
deleteFirst a (b:bc) | a == b    = bc 
                     | otherwise = b : deleteFirst a bc

> print $ deleteFirst 3 (3:3:2:1:9:7:3:[])
> [3,2,1,9,7,3]
```

Comment: Uh, I see sepp2k and Joachim Breitner already mentioned the fix.

Comment: Doesn't prelude have a built in for this?

Answer (score 6):

No, it's not possible using a list comprehension. In a list comprehension you make a decision which element to keep based on that element only. In your example, you want to treat the first 3 you encounter differently than other 3s (because you only want to remove the first one), so the decision does not depend on the element alone. So a list comprehension won't work.

Your attempt using a recursive function is already pretty close, except that, as you said, it removes all instances. Why does it remove all instances? Because after you removed the first one, you call `deleteFirst` again on the rest of the list, which will remove the next instance and so on. To fix this, just do not call `deleteFirst` again after removing the first instance. So just use `bc` instead of `deleteFirst a bc` in that case.

Answer (score 2):

I don’t believe it is possible to do this with list comprehension (at least not in in any idiomatic way).

Your `deleteFirst` works almost. All you need to change to fix is is to stop deleting after the first match, i.e. replace `deleteFirst a bc` in the first clause by `bc`.

Answer (score 0):

sepp2k's remarks about list comprehensions are an important thing to understand; list operations like `map`, `filter`, `foldr` and so on treat all list items uniformly, and the important thing to understand about them is what information is available at each step, and how each step's result is combined with those of other steps.

But the aspect I want to stress is that I think you should really be trying to solve these problems in terms of library functions.  Adapting the solution from [this older answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14137172/replace-an-element-in-a-list-only-once-haskell/14150282#14150282) to your problem:

```
deleteFirst x xs = beforeX ++ afterX
    -- Split the list into two pieces:
    --   * prefix = all items before first x
    --   * suffix = all items after first x
    where (beforeX, xAndLater) = break (/=x) xs
          afterX = case xAndLater of
                     [] -> []
                     (_:xs) -> xs
```

The trick is that `break` already has the "up to first hit" behavior built in it.  As a further exercise, you can try writing your own version of `break`; it's always instructive to learn how to write these small, generic and reusable functions.