# Using List Comprehension in place of Recursion

Tags: haskell

I am curious whether or not using list comprehension in place of recursion is possible for the following example.

The function `replaceFirst` that takes in an an element and a list and replaces the first occurrence of the element from the list.

This can be done using recursion as follows:

```
replaceFirst _ [] = []
replaceFirst elem y (x:xs) | x==y = (elem:xs)
                           | otherwise = x:replaceFirst elem y xs
```

My question is, can this recursive function, or a similar recursive function that operates on the first occurrence of an element in a list, be replaced with a list comprehension function? Why or why not? (I am more concerned with the reasoning than the actual code).

Comment: Isn’t this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14688716/removing-the-first-instance-of-x-from-a-list? The difference between deleting and replacing is not so big, and doesn’t affect whether it can be done with list recursion or not.

Comment: The first equation is missing a pattern.

Comment: It might help to think of the list comprehension as `foreach` loop where you can apply filter and computation to each element. See `do` syntax for list monad in this wiki http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/List_comprehension

Answer (score 8, accepted):

List comprehensions are [syntactic sugar](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-420003.11) for various forms of `map`, `filter,` and `concatMap`. If your recursive function can be described in terms of these, then you can rewrite it to a list comprehension. They can't short circuit, as you do above, nor can they pass accumulating state.

Your `replaceFirst` would seem to require an accumulator to "tell" later elements in the list about the appearance of earlier elements. I think this makes it difficult or impossible to write using only list comprehension syntax.

Comment: +1, thanks for the reply. I was having a hard time determining whether this can be done using, list comp alone, but your answer just clarified and confirmed my first instinct. Thanks!

Comment: @MiGusta: Right, though of course this doesn't mean the function can't be rewritten using _other_ standard higher-order functions. `replaceFirst elem y xs | (l,_:r)<-break(==y)xs = l++[elem]++r | otherwise = xs` would work.

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension, inspired by leftaroundabout:

```
replaceFirst elem y xs = [a | let b = break (==y) xs
                                  c = if not (null $ snd b) 
                                         then fst b ++ [elem] ++ tail (snd b) 
                                         else fst b
                              , a <- c]
```