# Removing the first instance of an element (Haskell)

Tags: visual-studio, haskell, ghci

I am new to working with haskell but I tried to follow the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14688716/removing-the-first-instance-of-x-from-a-list) question to create my own function that takes a list and an element as input and removes the first instance of said element from list.

My code looks like this:

```
rem1 :: Eq a => [a] -> a -> [a]
rem1 [] _ = []
rem1 ys _ = ys
rem1 (y:ys) x   | x == y    = ys
                | otherwise = y : rem1 ys x
```

The code compiles when I load it in ghci, but when I test it the list is unchanged. Like so:

```
Ok, one module loaded.
ghci> rem1 "abab" 'b'
"abab"
```

When it should be like this:

```
Ok, one module loaded.
ghci> rem1 "abab" 'b'
"aab"
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: GHC would warn about this mistake if we turned on warnings with `-Wall` -- I recommend that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any argument except an empty list, the second case always fires:

```
rem1 ys _ = ys
```

It says "whatever the arguments are, always return the first argument". So it does.

You were probably thinking about the second case "in comparison" with the third case: the third case matches on `(:)`, and the second case matches "when there is no `(:)`".

But that's not how pattern matching works. A pattern like `ys` matches anything, anything at all, regardless of whether it's the `(:)` constructor or not. So your second case matches any parameter.

To fix, just remove the second case. You don't need it.